# Add photo to my app and store in Core Data

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, camera

I have created a very basic app that lists a bunch of Employee names in a table, when you click on the person's name it brings you up information about them.  I would like to develop this app a little further and be able to show a picture of the person too beside their info.

When the app first runs you can click on the + top right corner to create a new employee, this segues to another View Controller, here you fill out the new employee information but I have left a space to the top left for being able to add a photograph of the employee weather it be retrieved from the camera roll or can be taken from the camera. I have created an image attribute in the Employee Entity and set it to type Binary Data but this is as far as I have got.

I'm guessing I drag on an Image View top left where I would like the image to go and then two buttons, one for take photo and one for camera roll, or is this the wrong way to go about this?

So once the photo has been taken or loaded from camera roll when i click on the save button I need it to save in core data.  I also have a View Controller for Editing the information so I would like to be able to change the picture with another one from the camera roll or take a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Store as NSData, Display as UIImage

Conversion from data to image :

```
NSData *data = LoadyourDataFromYouDB;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Conversion from image to data

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(YourUIImage);
```